# I need a word that is for when something implies another thing will happen

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Basically, I have a sentence that says something that happened and the following sentence explains what happens in response. The response is inevitable so the occurrence implies the response. I need a more powerful word than "therefore" or "thus."

Comment: Can you give a sample sentence with a space for the missing word? The first word that comes to mind is 'consequently'.

Comment: perhaps ***inevitably***

Answer (score 2):

You actually used the word I would have suggested in your question.

"A happened. [**Inevitably**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inevitably), B followed."

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **1** : in an inevitable way
> **2** : as is to be expected
> // *inevitably*, it rained
>
> **inevitable**
>
> : incapable of being avoided or evaded
> // an *inevitable* outcome

Answer (score 0):

**ergo**  [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/ergo)

(used as a sentence connector) therefore or consequently

As in to 'logically follow':

> You were present during the robbery; **ergo**, you were called as a
>   witness.

and

> Her rise to fame eclipses his star wattage, ergo, exacerbating his
>   already bleak downward spiral. Los Angeles Times Oct 4, 2018